# Mysterious newline appears in Common Lisp format directive

Tags: format, common-lisp, string-formatting, clisp

I'm running into an odd issue with Common Lisp's `format` directive that only shows itself in GNU CLISP, which leads me to wonder if it's a bug in the implementation.

Consider the following code

```
(defun f (s args)
  (format nil "~A~{~A~%~}" s args))
```

The function `f` produces a string consisting of the `s` argument, followed by each argument, where each argument (but *not* the header) is followed by a newline. So, for instance, I would expect

```
(format t "~A" (f "foo" '("arg1" "arg2")))
```

to produce

```
fooarg1
arg2
```

which it does, correctly. Now, consider the following calls

```
(format t "~A" (f "a" ()))
(format t "~A" (f "b" ()))
(format t "~A" (f "c" '("d")))
```

Given that the only newlines I ever print out are following elements from the second argument of `f`, and the first two calls pass an empty list for the second `f` argument, I expect to see no newlines until the very end, i.e. I expect this to print

```
abcd
```

It does exactly this in SBCL. However, in GNU CLISP, I get

```
ab
cd
```

Note the newline between `b` and `c`.

Changing the code to

```
(format t "~S" (f "a" ()))
(format t "~S" (f "b" ()))
(format t "~S" (f "c" '("d")))
```

shows the following, even less illuminating, results

```
"a""b"
"cd
"
```

So the newline between `b` and `c` is not part of either of the strings. Why is CLISP deciding to print a newline in between these `format` statements? And how can I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature of GNU CLISP. See the [documentation of `*pprint-first-newline*`](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/multi-rep.html#ppr-first-newline).

If you want a different output than that, bind either `*print-pretty*` or `*pprint-first-newline*` to nil during your `format` invocation.